# JPA/Hibernate and messed up named parameters

Tags: hibernate, jpa, prepared-statement, jpql

My simple query looks like this on JPQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(r) FROM org.domain.Resource r WHERE r._parent = :parent AND r._metadata[:metadataKey] is not null
```

But Hibernate SQL output looks like this (both for H2 and MySQL):

```
select
            count(resource0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
        from
            resources resource0_,
            resource_metadata metadata1_ 
        where
            resource0_.id=metadata1_.resource_id 
            and metadata1_.datum_key = ? 
            and resource0_.parent_id=? 
            and (
                metadata1_.datum_value is not null
            ) limit ?
```

The problem here is the known [bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2866) in Hibernate which messes up prepared statement parameters. So in my case parent and key are mixed.

Any suggestions for a work around apart from native query?

Comment: You mean, other than fixing the bug?

Comment: Yea, one option would be to write native query but that is against the whole idea of using JPA/Hibernate.